Detect JavaScript error with headless_chrome
I am trying to use the Rust crate headless_chrome to run some JavaScript and detect when it throws an error. Below is what I have so far. I have just been using trial and error as the crate has almost no docs unfortunately. I was hoping the console.assert(false); would generate an event I can listen for, but it doesn't seem to.
use headless_chrome::{protocol::cdp::types::Event, Browser, LaunchOptions};
use std::{error::Error, sync::Arc};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let browser = Browser::new(
        LaunchOptions::default_builder()
            .window_size(Some((2000, 2000)))
            .build()
            .expect("Could not find chrome-executable"),
    )?;
    let tab = browser.new_tab()?;
    tab.enable_debugger().unwrap();
    tab.enable_log().unwrap();

    let _events = tab.add_event_listener(Arc::new(move |event: &Event| {
        dbg!(event);
        if let Event::DebuggerPaused(_paused_event) = event {
            panic!("found js error");
        }
    }))?;

    let _remote_object = tab.evaluate("console.assert(false);", true).unwrap();

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));

    Ok(())
}


Try catching RuntimeExceptionThrown.

@ChayimFriedman Thanks. The only events being caught are DebuggerScriptParsed and InspectorDetached.

Hmm... Try calling Tab::call_method() directly with Evaluate (look at how Tab::evaluate() does it). It returns EvaluateReturnObject that contains exception_details.

so exception_details is None for console.assert(false);  because it turns out console.assert doesn't actually throw and seems more akin to writing to stderr. For my use case it makes more sense to introduce a function assert() { ... } that does actually throw so I think it is problem solved. Thanks (*again) for your help! *You previously answered the same question for me but for the chromiumoxide crate.
